# host_tracker module not working

Tags: python, openflow, sdn, pox

I want to use the host_tracker module in POX.
I have a tree topology running with mininet.
In the pox console, I run this command `$./pox.py host_tracker openflow.discovery`
When the links are detected I try to ping from my mininet console, `$h1 ping h2`, but it says destination host unreachable.
Here is the sample output.
POX:

```
anusha@anusha-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/pox$ ./pox.py host_tracker openflow.discovery
POX 0.2.0 (carp) / Copyright 2011-2013 James McCauley, et al.
INFO:host_tracker:host_tracker ready
INFO:core:POX 0.2.0 (carp) is up.
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0b 1] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0a 2] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-08 3] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-04 4] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0c 5] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-05 6] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-06 8] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-07 7] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0e 11] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-09 9] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-03 10] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0d 12] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-01 14] connected
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-02 13] connected
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-0b.1 -> 00-00-00-00-00-08.4
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-0b.2 -> 00-00-00-00-00-07.1
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-0a.4 -> 00-00-00-00-00-07.3
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-0a.2 -> 00-00-00-00-00-08.1
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.3 -> 00-00-00-00-00-0d.3
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 5 9e:b2:40:66:d3:32
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.6 -> 00-00-00-00-00-09.1
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 14 2 82:78:86:86:ad:3a
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 13 4 ee:5b:06:e7:48:b9
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.5 -> 00-00-00-00-00-0e.4
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 3 46:e8:77:ac:78:19
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 4 1 3e:f1:35:11:9a:f3
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 14 3 12:80:3e:1a:ec:33
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.1 -> 00-00-00-00-00-0a.2
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 3 4 4e:cd:16:8b:b7:f1
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 12 3 46:4c:24:94:fd:15
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 14 1 7a:78:3b:2d:97:e2
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.4 -> 00-00-00-00-00-0b.1
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 9 2 ca:f7:9e:00:fc:0b
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 3 3 52:97:b6:bc:31:ea
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 4 3 76:f0:75:c7:66:f8
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-08.2 -> 00-00-00-00-00-0c.1
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 7 6 ee:16:95:32:2a:6a
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 2 a2:58:e8:02:70:8f
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 7 4 52:67:ec:5b:b7:c8
INFO:openflow.discovery:link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-04.3 -> 00-00-00-00-00-01.3
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 2 6 f6:f4:c4:be:b1:7a
```

and in mininet:

```
mininet> h1_1_1 ping h1_1_2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7038ms
```

Can anybody tell why is the destination host not reachable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load a stock component with pox

```
python pox.py forwarding.l2_pairs host_tracker openflow.discovery
```

and run mininet with a remote controller

```
sudo mn --controller remote
```

then issue a pingall in mininet and monitor results in the pox terminal

Comment: Thanks! that worked :) Also can you tell me why we need to use forwarding.l2_pairs?

Comment: With my own custom topology, it gives some duplicate warning, any idea why? :/ `INFO:host_tracker:Learned 4 1 b2:99:d4:1c:d5:32 moved to 13 4
WARNING:host_tracker:Possible duplicate: 4 1 b2:99:d4:1c:d5:32 at time 1460042645, now (13 4), time 1460042645`

Comment: forwarding.l2_pairs is a sample controller (stock component) that will handle the network and flows modifications. You can use additional stock components that will help you start building your own at https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-StockComponents

Comment: As for the duplicate is because macs and ips currently assigned randomly by mininet. Use the miniedit http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-miniedit-mininets-graphical-user-interface/ and experiment with options for net something like `autoSetMacs=False`